# What is a Sample in Helm?

Tags: haskell, frp, elm

There doesn't seem to be much documentation for `Sample a` in the Haskell FRP library Helm. I am trying to write a function similar to [`sample on`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.0.1/Signal#sampleOn) in Elm and I think `update` could help. However I am confused about how `update` works because, from the source code [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/helm-0.7.0/docs/FRP-Helm-Sample.html),  it seems that the variable `p` is not used at all.

What should this function be doing and why is the input `p` included if it isn't used? Is there a better way to do this? I think `seq` could work, but I tried implementing my animation with `seq` and it doesn't do the thing I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the first argument there exists for historical reasons or for consistency with other functions offered by helm; but I don't know enough about either to say for sure.

The intended use of the `update` function seems to be to wrap the appropriate constructor around its argument: `update p a s` will result in either `Changed a` or `Unchanged a` depending on whether `a` matches with the value stored in `s`. One might use this, for example, as an argument to `foldp`:

```
foldp (update undefined) :: Eq a => Sample a -> Signal a -> Signal (Sample a)
```

Downstream signals could then ignore `Unchanged` values easily.